Is every smooth surface locally an elliptic paraboloid, hyperbolic paraboloid, plane or cylinder?
Is it true that for any smooth surface in $\mathbb R^3$, a sufficiently small region is approximated (up to arbitrarily small error) by either:

A plane
A parabolic cylinder
An elliptic paraboloid
A hyperbolic paraboloid

Is it correct to conclude that every smooth surface is correspondingly either:

Flat
No Gaussian curvature, but not necessarily flat
Positive Gaussian curvature
Negative Gaussian curvature

Motivation
I believe this is correct because, by the Taylor series, we have $$z(x,y) = Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F + \mathcal{O}((|x|+|y|)^3).$$  Translation and rotation allows us to write $$w(u,v) = Pu^2 + Qv^2$$ which is either a plane ($P = Q = 0$), a cylinder ($PQ = 0$), an elliptic parabaloid ($PQ > 0$) or a hyperbolic paraboloid ($PQ < 0$).
Update - Definition
By approximated I mean the following:
For every $(x_0,y_0)$ there exists a function $a(x,y)$ such that $$|a(x,y) - z(x,y)| = \mathcal{O}((|x-x_0| + |y - y_0|)^3).$$  Of course, defining approximated is itself perhaps the most important part of the question, so I'm open to alternate definitions.

What do you mean by "approximated"?

@MoisheKohan Updated with definition.

Yes, this is correct. I would say zero Gaussian curvature, rather than no.

Oh, but flat means zero curvature. You mean non-planar. Actually, I was too hasty. There is an error here: A surface may have a planar point — or have zero curvature — at one point but have positive or negative curvature at some or all nearby points.

@TedShifrin Can you give an example of such a surface?

Sure: How about $z=x^4\pm y^4$?
